# ES6 Chaining Access Previous Method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, chaining

I have a problem with ES6 Class Chaining.
I have a class as in the example. I want to access baz() method callback. I want to use that callback inside WorkHard class. How can I do that?

```js
class WorkHard {

  constructor() {
    this.value_1 = []
    this.value_2 = []
  }
  
  foo(args) {
    this.value_1 = args;
    return this;
  }
  
  baz(cb) {
    this.value_1 = null;
    this.value_2 = null;
    return this;
  }
  
  zoo(args) {
    this.value_2 = args;
    return this;
  }
  
}
```

```js
const WorkHard = new WorkHard();

WorkHard.foo('TestValue_1').baz(() => {
  console.log('This is baz() method content.');
}).zoo('TestValue_2')
```

Comment: `baz(cb) {cb(); ...; return this;}`

Comment: Where and when do you want to call `cb()`?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to create chaining system like Adonis.js. You can check that system. Those methods get, post, group, prefix, middleware. I want to create chaining system like Adonis.js. Bu for different purpose of course.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know adonis. Please make your question self-contained, by at least including expected output of your sample call.

Comment: I think I've asked wrong question. Sorry for it. I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `cb` anywhere inside your class.
Also, your instance cannot have the same name as the class.

Just execute `cb` inside `baz`.

```js
class WorkHard {

  constructor() {
    this.value_1 = []
    this.value_2 = []
  }
  
  foo(args) {
    this.value_1 = args;
    console.log('foo called');
    return this;
  }
  
  baz(cb) {
    this.value_1 = null;
    this.value_2 = null;
    cb();
    return this;
  }
  
  zoo(args) {
    console.log('zoo called');
    this.value_2 = args;
    return this;
  }
  
}

const workHard = new WorkHard();

workHard.foo('TestValue_1').baz(() => {
  console.log('This is baz() method content.');
}).zoo('TestValue_2')
```

If you want the callback to control the chaining flow, keep in mind a callback returns nothing by itself, so you would need to also return that function call instead of `this`

```
 // inside WorkHard
 baz(cb) {
   this.value_1 = null;
   this.value_2 = null;
   return cb(this);
 }


workHard.foo('TestValue_1').baz((instance) => {
  console.log('Workhard visible variables are', instance);
  return instance;
}).zoo('TestValue_2');
```

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks a lot. I'll let you know.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to create chaining system like Adonis.js. You can check that system. Those methods get, post, group, prefix, middleware. I want to create chaining system like Adonis.js. Bu for different purpose of course.